# starting Appium in port 4723 redirects to port 8200

Tags: java, appium, appium-java

Currently I am starting programmatically an Appium server with the following capabilities

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.0");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "apk/path");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

This are logs from Appium.
[image]

But it ends up redirecting it to port 8200
[image]

Anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed a lot of weird behaviour when connecting to the loopback address (`0.0.0.0`), so it might be related to that.

Try starting Appium by explicitly binding to localhost,  which you can do with the `--address` argument, eg `--address 127.0.0.1`.

Then, update your connection string to `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub`.